# Block Gallery View in Finder on macOS

Tags: macos, finder, security

macOS seems to have a fairly serious security issue that allows users to browse the Internet without any restrictions, even with device control software installed.

Chrome allows you to save any website to your desktop and preview it in Gallery View through the viewfinder.

Below is the process:

1. Go to any website on Chrome, website is blocked at this stage by filter
2. Save As (Web Page, HTML Only)
3. In Finder, go to Gallery View and the website loads all text and images, CSS etc.

**Can the gallery view in Finder, be permanently blocked? Using the terminal or settings?**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  Have a look at our [tour] so you can have a great experience.

Answer (score 1):

No, Safari and Finder would need to not be given a URL to look up.

You will have to implement a different strategy for security than installing Chrome and (thus far undocumented and theoretical) Chrome extensions that allow you to save links and data you do not which to be consumed by the system.

Basically, you need better device control than a quick fix.

Comment: Thank you, bmike. Your response is greatly appreciated. Would you be able to give me any recommendations I could explore further? This is something I really want to make work...

Comment: Not really, I have no idea what your goals are @Mark85

Comment: Coldturkey is currently blocking websites and I have created a profile using iMazing to prevent users to make any changes to the system. 

Safe browsing is the goal. With no preview option for downloaded websites. 

Chrome works like a dream at the moment. It's just the preview feature in the finder that's causing problems.

Comment: You need to stop chrome from saving files - it’s game over for your model of control if you can’t stop the system from knowing about and reaching these sites. Anyone with text edit can type in the address and quick look, preview, download content. These “tests” are just breaking your illusion you’ve controlled or  secured the system. Content filters work better at the network model than on one app.